# ASP.net flow chart of pages in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i am not sure how to put what i am looking for. The best i can describe it is a flowchart type of layout that shows your all your ASP.NET pages and how they are linked to one another.

Example:

```
-----------              -----------
|main page|              |error.asp|
-----------\             /----------
            \-----------/           ------------
            | login.asp|            |footer.asp|
            ------------\           /-----------
                         \---------/  ------------
                         |Home.asp|---|Header.asp|
                         ----------\  ------------
                        /           \------------
                     --/----------- |Nav bar.asp|
                     |Products.asp| -------------           
                     --------------
```

etc etc..

Is there any built-in things like that or 3rd party software that does what i am looking to do above?

Thanks!

**Update**
I meant for something like this to be part of the VB.net IDE (Visual Studio 2008) :o)

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/22/ask-sm-how-to-create-a-colorful-sitemap-with-jquery/

Comment: Sorry Robert. I wasn't detailed enough. I need it to be inside the IDE.

Comment: In the IDE, wouldn't it only work for static, and not dynamic, pages?